# SQL:102,15 Incorrect syntax near "="

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working in program which one some T-SQL.

Part of code:

```
SELECT
hvw_EvZar.ID,hvw_EvZar.BlokovaniEditoru,hvw_EvZar.NazovZariadenia,hvw_EvZar.CisloOrganizacie
FROM hvw_EvZar
WHERE
(:CisloOrg =hvw_EvZar.CisloOrganizacie)

CASE
    WHEN TabCisOrg.CisloOrg IS NULL THEN TabCisOrg.NadrizenaOrg = hvw_EvZar.CisloOrganizacie
    ELSE TabCisOrg.CisloOrg = hvw_EvZar.CisloOrganizacie
END
ORDER BY
3 ASC /* TabCisOrg.CisloOrg */,13 ASC /* TabCisOrg.Firma */
```

Displayed error

> [SQL:102,15] Incorrect syntax near "=".

I tried also to add spaces around "=" but it didn't help.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you're using (likely SQL Server, but will leave it to you to ensure the validity of such an assumption on my part) - answers may vary materially between each dialect.

Comment: It's not possible to diagnose this issue without seeing the query as a [mre], along with an explanation of what *exactly* it is you're trying to do. [ask]

Comment: It is not `UPDATE` - you are not changing field values.  You are simply defining an output column.  So you do not any assignments inside your `THEN` and `ELSE`.

Comment: After THEN you should have an expression resulting in a value. There shouldn't be any =, you cannot assign there

Comment: Okay i understand, so how to assign some value if some conditions are true ? If you are saying i cant do any assignments inside THEN and ELSE

Comment: more code was added to see whole query :)

Comment: You don't have the table `TabCisOrg` joined on though?

Comment: It is joined, but it is not visible in this code because it is joined already by software (CRM system).

Because i am writing this SQL code into our company's  CRM system. I dont have access to whole code so i am only adding that CASE as condition.

Comment: Please explain all that in your question because otherwise it doesn't make sense to those of us who don't know that background.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `CASE` expression for this situation, just boolean logic operators e.g.

```
AND (
    (T.CisloOrg IS NULL AND T.NadrizenaOrg = H.CisloOrganizacie)
    OR (T.CisloOrg IS NOT NULL AND T.CisloOrg = H.CisloOrganizacie)
)
```

Notes:

- You should (if possible) use short, meaningful, table aliases for clarify.
- Also as a best practice do not use ordinal column values in your order by clause. Use the column names.
- Please read the documentation - [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an *expression* not a *statement* as as such can only return a value.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but after using your code i got this error:

**[SQL:156,15] Incorrect syntax near keyword "AND".**

Comment: Yeah it can be caused by CRM... I am using **HELIOS** from company **ASSECO solutions**

They are everywhere saying, like they use T-SQL syntax but it seems like it does not work...

Comment: I've shown you the correct logic for how to structure your query which answers your question since your question makes no mention of a CRM etc. So its up to you (maybe with the help of a new question tagging the CRM) to work out how to integrate it with your existing query.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, i will try to discuss this with people from CRM company